# WiFi dongle for packets sniffing with Raspberry Pi

Tags: python, networking, wifi, wireless, wireless-adapter

I would like to create a simple wifi network sniffer using raspberry pi. I am going to use the Wireshark Python API (now pyreshark) to make a live capture and packet analysis.

The question I have is if the [Adafruit Wifi Dongle](https://www.adafruit.com/products/814) would be a good choice for this project?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The adapter does not list Monitor or Promiscuous as supported modes. In order for Wireshark to listen, the adapter should be configured in either of the above two modes.